# NSUserDefaults object leaked

Tags: iphone

After Analyzing in Xcode , I got "Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in his execution path and has a retain count +1"

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int iValue = [defaults integerForKey:@"KEY"];
```

Do I need to release default?

Answer (score 2):

No, the issue much be somewhere else in your code. Both of these objects are autoreleased.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Xcode analyze shows "object leaked:" message, What happened?

Comment: Maybe include more code around the line it says its on. Im sure it also says the line #, double check that line and post it here.